# Laravel route prefix matches public folder directory

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5.3

I have a route prefix of "app" such that my users can go to "www.abc.com/app/xyz".

All my assets for that web app are saved in an "app" directory in the public folder.

Currently if someone were to go to "www.abc.com/app" in their browser they are getting an NGINX error of "Forbidden".

I believe this is happening because the prefix for my app routes matches the folder in the public directory.

Is there a way to catch this before the error hits the screen and redirect the user to a specific location before they see the ugly error?

Answer (score 0):

You can move root index.php and .htacess to root_app/html;

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you are suggesting, can you explain a little?

Comment: Can you post nginx config?

Comment: um, nope. It is just standard homestead